# App store rejection for my app with external device

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I am using a external device with tcp/ip socket connection and i need to upload to app store. How apple will review this app ?
Do i need to send my device to apple for review?

Comment: This question is not related to programming, so I am flagging it as off-topic. But I'll help you here. You just have to make a short demo video showing the full features of the app and how it interacts with the device. Then upload that video and include a link to it under "notes" in App Review Information. Then you should also state there that the app needs a device in order to use the features, and tell them that this link would be a demo for the app controlling the device.

Comment: I have an app in App Store which have similar functionality. As mentioned by @JLT, I've uploaded a video for apple review team to verify the working and they approved the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
This is valid only if you are using external accessory capability.

If it is just a device communication via LAN no need to do this (eg. LAN printer)

// -----

you must contact device manufacturer and then they will register your app id and send you back a MFi id that you can use.

check this out
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Authorized manufacturers are already registered with apple, so they can register your app to use with their device.